# Metric on the Grassmannians

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Can we define a metric or induced metric written in terms of Plücker coordinates on any complex Grassmannian?

By induced metric, I mean the metric we get by reducing $N(N-1)$ Plücker coordinates to $k(N-k)$ linearly independent Plücker coordinates on $\mathbf{Gr}_k(\mathbb{C}^N)$ in any given patch via Plücker relation and conditions derived from the embedding of the manifold into $\mathbb{CP}^{\left(\begin{array}{c}
N\\
k
\end{array}\right)
 -1}$ manifold.

Thanks in advance

AB